# Abnormal Behaviour of Web Browser

Tags: java, spring-boot, browser

I was working on a Spring-security LDAP application. I'm following the link - https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/ . Problem I'm facing is that I have made a very simple controller and a method to handle a request, returning a string. But browser is opening a login page (which I can't find anywhere). I deleted cache, restarted Eclipse and system both but to my dismay it displays the same page irrespective of any url configured in controller or any port. I'm unable to elucidate this behavior of browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you had followed the guide exactly as it is, then you may notice that the file WebSecurityConfig.java has the following line

```
http.authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
    .and().formLogin();
```

Which means that all your requests need to be authenticated. That means any end points that you define need to be authenticated too. They are secured by default.

You seem to have made a GET request to your endpoint, which is secured by Spring Security. If you want to create an unsecure endpoint then you have to make changes to the WebSecurityConfig file.

The login page that you mention is provided by Spring security library itself. It won't be available in your cloned project. At the end of the page they have also mentioned that the username is **ben** and password is **benspassword**. Spring security provides lot of default options which are useful. But, unless you read the documentation to understand what they are, you are in for quite a few surprises.

Comment: Thank you Amudhan for your reply! But I have not yet implemented Security in application. I have just created a simple controller and defined a method in it returning a string value.